# Visual Studio 2019: How to use Platform Toolset v140_xp?

Tags: c++, windows-xp, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to compile an application for Windows XP using Visual Studio 2019. For that I tried to use platform toolset v140_xp. It does not work, the following error message appears:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Platforms\Win32\PlatformToolsets\v140_xp\Toolset.targets(36,5): warning MSB8003: Could not find WindowsSdkDir_71A variable from the registry.  TargetFrameworkVersion or PlatformToolset may be set to an invalid version number.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(366,5): warning MSB8003: Could not find WindowsSDKDir variable from the registry.  TargetFrameworkVersion or PlatformToolset may be set to an invalid version number.
```

Clearly, the tools are looking for the Windows SDK v7.1A. Downloading the Windows 7 SDK from Microsoft does not work. Even if you manage to install it, the SDK has version 7.1 (without the A) and not 7.1A. So the error remains.

I have found out that the Windows SDK v7.1A used to be included with Visual Studio 2015, but I cannot find it anywhere in the Visual Studio 2019 installer.

How do I use the v140_xp toolset?

Steps to reproduce the problem:

- install Visual Studio 2019 with desktop c++ development
- select "MSVC v140 - VS2015 C++ Build tools" in the visual studio 2019 installer
- create a C++ console application project
- edit the project settings
- select the v140_xp platform toolset
- try to build the project

Answer (score 10):

In the Visual Studio 2019 Installer, the Windows SDK 7.1A is hidden behind the option "C++ Windows XP Support for VS 2017 (v141) tools [Deprecated]".

Hovering the mouse over that option a tooltip appears that states that Windows SDK 7.1 is included with that component.

The whole procedure is described here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/configuring-programs-for-windows-xp?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 9):

**Updated** for someone who will be confused by installer GUI like me.

There are "Individual Components" **tab** on the top, and "Individual Components" **check list** on the left.

Checking "C++ Desktop Development" **does not** trigger all C++ components to appear in check list. "WinXP support" must be checked in tab first, and **then** it appears in check list:

[image]

See also:
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/cpp-docs/issues/1810

Comment: What issue do you have with my answer? The option "C++ Windows XP for VS2017 (v141) [deprecated]" is still available in the VS2019 installer and it works. I tested a small Hello World program.

Comment: @Sven: The first screenshot in my post is from VS2019 Installer - there's no such option. 140 and 141 toolsets are available, but not 140_xp or 141_xp. It's Enterprise edition in my case. Actually, I found your answer, and for some time tried to understand, what am I doing wrong, and *where* is this option. :) Maybe, it depends on VS installer version/edition/or something else.

Comment: I have 16.4.5 and it's still there for me. Not sure if it's a matter of "version", or "already having the thing installed to begin with".

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/configuring-programs-for-windows-xp?view=vs-2019

According to the link you have to install "C++ Windows XP Support for VS 2017 (v141) tools [Deprecated]"

Comment: I just upgraded to Visual Studio 2019 16.5.0 Community edition and the option is still there.

Comment: @Sven: the problem was "**where** to find this checkbox". Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

using visual studio installer and install v140 and v141_xp